# problem in connecting to my EC2 instance from android simulator

Tags: android, rest, android-emulator, amazon-ec2

i am facing strange problem i deployed a webservice in EC2 which is up and working fine, but when i am trying to do a REST request on these service I am getting java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out. When i am trying the same URL in my laptop browser it is working but when i am trying this in Android emulator browser it is giving me error.

here is my code

REST URL: http://122.248.194.88:8080/data_for?train=12657

code:-

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://122.248.194.88:8080/data_for?train=12658"); 

        // Execute the request
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

`

this httpclient.execute is returning the socket exception is there anything more which i need to know??

I am behind a proxy though but i set that proxy in eumulator options while starting the emulator.

Comment: it is not simulator,it is emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the example here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html to consume a JSON string.  It works perfectly.

Comment: yess permission is set i am able to access google from my browser

Comment: this works fine for me also but when i am trying my URL i am getting the same Time out exception on line  InputStream source = retrieveStream(url); i dont know what is wrong can you try with my code??